# Restkit fails after the first failed response

Tags: ios, restkit

Using RestKit and if I pass in a good URL everything works fine. If I pass in a bad URL the first time then all subsequent calls fails even if I have the correct URL.

I think something is getting cached or something with RestKit (e.g. RKObjectManager) is being reused.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The shared RKClient was set I guess by the objectManager, but calling again and setting up a new objectManager or using the existing one the shared RKClient is not updating its baseURL.

So I do this manually.

[[RKClient sharedClient] setBaseURL:url];